# if the string is "yash" then how can we can the output in the form of yyaasshh

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

```
double_char('The') → 'TThhee'
double_char('AAbb') → 'AAAAbbbb'
double_char('Hi-There') → 'HHii--TThheerree'
```

what is the code for this

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a free homework service.  Please edit the question to include your progress on solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each character and then duplicate each letter and append it to a new variable

```
def double_char(str):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(str)):
        result = result + str[i] + str[i]
    return result
```